# Words created by permutations of a 7-letter word in a grid

Tags: logical-deduction, word-search

Below is a 7x7 square grid. On the top row is a single word with seven letters. From the permutation of the letters of this word, one word has been created. Is it possible to create a solution with 15 words (Merriam-Webster online dictionary) from a single 7-letter word (of your choice) in the top row, using permutations? Words can be read horizontally, vertically  and diagonally. The following restrictions apply: No two same letters are allowed to appear in any row any column or in either of the two diagonals.

[image: letter grid containing permutations of the word 'century' and the word CENT next to it. Replicated below.]

*addendum*: If you put the word ARTICLE in the top row and then perform the permutations in the sequence of the given example, then more than 10 words are created. Here are 10 of them: ART, ARTIC, EAR, LEA, CLEAR, RECTAL, TIC, LEAR, IRE, TALI.

2nd *addendum*: The word maximum was not intended to be interpreted with mathematical meaning, because it is impossible to calculate the maximum number of word with traditional mathematical methods. I changed the wording of the puzzle.

As a table for accessibility:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | E | N | T | U | R | Y |
| R | Y | C | E | N | T | U |
| T | U | R | Y | C | E | N |
| E | N | T | U | R | Y | C |
| Y | C | E | N | T | U | R |
| U | R | Y | C | E | N | T |
| N | T | U | R | Y | C | E |

> CENT

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without defining "word" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Comment: @bobble the question defines what are considered words by specifying a dictionary, no? We can make it more specific by providing a word list from a version of the dictionary that we are supposed to use for this question. But that aside, the question is still unclear, can we read the word backwards? What is our task here? Pick a 7-letter word, then arrange it on the grid, and count the number of words formed in the grid, and maximize this number?

Comment: @bobble oxford english dictionary is mentioned

Comment: Are we only counting 7-letter words?

Comment: Okay, now you've edited in a dictionary (note to the two people who pinged me about my wrongness: the edit happened after my comment). Are computer solutions allowed? That's the only real way I can see to prove optimality

Comment: @justhalf The words can be read forwards and backwards. Yes, choose a 7-letter word and place it in the top row. Then, by permutation,  create as many words as possible. The grid is to be filled completely with the letters with the letters in the first row.

Comment: @Dmitry Kamenetsky All words are counted

Comment: @bobble All solutions allowed.

Comment: The question says "What is the maximum number of words we can create..." - also, if you just allow random solutions without any proof of optimality, this becomes an open-ended game/list

Comment: @bobble If you find a solution that contains 10 words I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: So is the question really "find a solution with 10 words"?

Comment: @bobble ah, my bad then, I didn't notice. Thanks for keeping the quality of question on this site good!

Comment: Is 'Cent' the only valid word in the example grid? If not can you provide an exhaustive list for this grid?

Comment: For the word  CENTURY only one word can be created,  but if you want more words try the word ARTICLE on the top row.

Comment: I can't search the OED but [en](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/en), [ent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ent), [Ur](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ur) come to mind...

Comment: @PuzzleFerret Only EN is a wort. The others are parts of words. I'm sorry I missed the EN.

Comment: https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry.dictionarywordwheel.view/ur$002c+n./$002fEntry$002f220311/ur-100/1846.415795?currentStartWord=Ur&t:ac=Entry%2F182171&t:formdata=H4sIAAAAAAAAAKWQsUoEMRCGcweCcI0c2Fhrm2s8kNXm4BSERcVFrbPJuBfNJjGZdW8bW619AJ9AfIkr7HwHH8DWSsRkT2wEUSxn4J%2Fv%2B%2Bf%2BhSzUCdk4llCPJUdpNHPNtkbXJOJrro0T9QRAUV45Bxo9Modx6x0ZGldQZhmfAEVmwYfskHLjQMmc5swDHeVhyTjuSFBiNQOs7NrRrPe8%2FPjWJZ2U9LgJRKP2WAlI%2BukZu2QDxXQxyNBJXWxOLZKlT3YW2SfR6H%2Feo796HzjDwfusykvpfSDMHsT66evdU5eQqa23SPJbG2xsaBVAhgkfz2HwGf%2Fow01pjY4VaCr1eSuB35X25c3t%2B8q1bt%2B6yJUMiV1xQa5IJ%2F6wPycftuT5jQ%2Fna1%2F2AgIAAA%3D%3D

Comment: I don't subscribe, but that looks like an entry in the OED for Ur

Comment: The link just leads to the OED home page.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWEWj.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132340/discussion-between-puzzleferret-and-vassilis-parassidis).

Comment: This "puzzle" is really a game whose objective is to find the best solution one can.  As @bobble pointed out, this community decided that such open-ended questions are off-topic here. Two suggestions, if you want to salvage this: (1) set a specific provable goal like you did in the comments—make the question "Does a solution with 10 words exist?"—since at that point the question is one that can potentially be provably answered;  (2) OED is a great decider of what-is-a-word in principle, but in practice many people cannot access it... consider a different, publicly accessible dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, Rubio, for your constructive suggestions.

Comment: Must there be exactly 15 words, or just at least that much?

Comment: If you get more  it's even better.

Comment: But doesn't that turn this back into a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?
Thanks to @PuzzleFerret to pointing out a rule I missed originally, but the answer still seems trivial. What did I miss this time?

Full solution:

1. put the word ARTICLE in the top row and then perform the permutations by shifting each row twice:

ARTICLE
LEARTIC
ICLEART
RTICLEA
EARTICL
CLEARTI
TICLEAR

2. find 15 words horizontally, vertically and diagonally, that are in the MW dictionary

Well, okay.  10 are given to us:
1)ART
2)ARTIC
3)EAR
4)LEA
5)CLEAR
6)RECTAL
7)TIC
8)LEAR
9)IRE
10)TALI

And here are the next 5:

> 11)TI
>  12)IT
>  13)AE
>  14)AT
>  15)EL
>  I now have no idea if reading backwards is permitted; the question seems ambiguous in that respect. But if so, just substitute RE or other words.